# Moving tongue to the back to prime explosive back strength?

Tags: pull-ups, calisthenics

This was a point mentioned by Dr. Staurt Mcgill to Brian Caroll when teaching him to prime himself to maximize the explosive power when pull uping. [Here](https://youtu.be/EdveLFrh9U8?si=iY0MigBgMkHwckne&t=27) is a time stamped video of the same.

Could someone explain the logic behind this advice? It seems quite absurd to me that the tongue position has anything to do with how well back muscles are primed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly putting the tongue on the [roof of the mouth activates the trigeminal nerve](https://www.elevatechiropractic.co.nz/blog/where-is-your-tongue-positioned-when-you-exercise) which causes your neck muscles to stiffen and stabilize the neck.

There was a study published in 2014 that turned a lot of heads which [studied tongue position with regards to performance output with isokinetic knee extensions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3940506/). It studied 18 healthy men and found that putting the tongue in the top of the mouth had a significant increase in power output. They suggested that putting the tongue on the top of the mouth triggers the nervous system in some way that translates down the body. [This paper makes the hypothesis that](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6390887/) that activating the trigeminal nerve "may induce modulating activity in the vestibular system". The [vestibular system](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK532978/#:%7E:text=The%20vestibular%20system%20functions%20to,signals%20from%20its%20individual%20components.) helps with eye coordination, movement, and posture. Other people have suggested a simpler mechanism in which tongue position really doesn't do anything, but consciously putting your tongue at the top of your mouth gets your brain thinking "UP UP UP" which is a cue that follows to whatever else it is you're doing.

It should be noted that the study was a pilot study with only 18 people, and after 9 years there doesn't seem to be anybody who has followed up on it. That doesn't seem to stop people from changing their whole training philosophy to accommodate it.

Having said all that, I'm not sure how Dr. Stuart McGill translates that to specifically back muscles. A lot of back exercises would be better with a stiff neck, so *if there is* something to it, then it can only help. He may have also just saying "maximizing power output" in general.

Comment: bruh moment maximal

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain the logic behind this advice?

It's safe to assume that there is none.

> It seems quite absurd to me that the tongue position has anything to do with how well back muscles are primed.

Your initial reaction is correct.